# CSS Select box arrow style

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the default arrow from the select box and want to use custom icon. From the previous answers on SO, I have found out that it is not possible (to make it work with major browsers). Only possibility is to wrap the select inside a div, and set its width more than the div width and setting overflow: hidden.
I am trying following, but it does not work. What I'm doing wrong?

```css
.selectParent {
  width: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.selectParent select {
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  padding: 2px 30px 2px 2px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png") no-repeat right center;
}
```

```html
<div class="selectParent">
  <select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>           
   </select>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/gcPmC/

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the way like below:

```css
.selectParent {
 width:120px;
 overflow:hidden;   
}
.selectParent select { 
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 2px 25px 2px 2px; 
 border: none; 
 background: url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png") right center no-repeat; 
 appearance: none; 
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none; 
}
.selectParent.left select {
 direction: rtl;
 padding: 2px 2px 2px 25px;
 background-position: left center;
}
/* for IE and Edge */ 
select::-ms-expand { 
 display: none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="selectParent">
  <select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>           
   </select>
</div>
<br />
<div class="selectParent left">
  <select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>           
   </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the

```
padding: 2px 30px 2px 2px;
```

with

```
padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks but my custom icon still doesnt appear.