# How to customized the select box using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

can anyone help me custom a select dropdown like this using bootstrap 3 please!.

i am trying many time but without success.
Thanks

[this is an example of what i am trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qvcg.png)

Comment: so basically, you want a [custom css box arrow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668404/css-select-box-arrow-style) using bootstrap's [form select](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls) right?

Comment: yes, i want to remove the border-radius and make a background for the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kK2HL/1/) from [bavotasan.com](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/)

```
.styled-select {
    width: 245px;
    height: 34px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:url(/*your-img-url-here*/) no-repeat right;
}

.styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   width: 110%;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 1;
   border-radius: 0;
   height: 34px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance:none;
}
```

note `-webkit-appearance`/`-moz-appearance` are not supported by opera or internet explorer, so it won't have the effect you want on all browsers.