# Select element with clickable image component

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm aiming to do a select element that has an icon next to it, like below. If the user clicks anywhere inside the "button" (including the icon), the option list should be displayed.

[image]

```
function Select() {
  return (
    <div>
      <select>
        <option value="">Choose an option</option>
        <option value="dog">Dog</option>
        <option value="cat">Cat</option>
        <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
      </select>
      <ImportedSvg />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I know there is a CSS way to solve this by having the [image as a background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49770265/1417223) to the `select` tag. As well as creating a custom option list.

However, I want the browser default option list and I need to use a React element for the image. And lastly, I don't want a library dependency to solve this (e.g. FontAwesome or Material UI).

Is there any way to accomplish the above?

Comment: Since you're usnig react why not use material-ui or some other framework for custom elements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it with a ridiculously simple approach - by absolute-positioning the image inside the `select` while giving the `select` transparent background.

Complete code (with `styled-components`):

```
const Wrapper = styled.div({
  alignItems: 'center',
  display: 'inline-flex',
  background: '#fff',
  position: 'relative',
})
const StyledSelect = styled.select({
  appearance: 'none',
  border: '1px solid #ccc',
  borderRadius: 4,
  height: 40,
  paddingRight: 30,
  zIndex: 20,
  paddingLeft: 12,
  background: 'transparent',
})
const StyledImageComponent = styled(ImageComponent)({
  position: 'absolute',
  zIndex: 10,
  right: 12,
})

export function Select({ options, onChange, currentValue }) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <StyledSelect onChange={onChange} defaultValue={currentValue}>
        {options.map(({ value, label }) => (
          <option key={value} value={value}>
            {label}
          </option>
        ))}
      </StyledSelect>
      <StyledImageComponent />
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-+N4/V/SbAFiW1MPBCXnfnP9QSN3+Keu+NlB+0ev/YKQ=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: white;    
  color: #525252;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
</style>
<body>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Choose an option <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Dog</a>
    <a href="#">Cat</a>
    <a href="#">Hamster</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably can use label instead of img. When click on label dropdown can be shown:

```js
return (
  <div>
    <select id={ id }>
      ...
    </select>
    <label htmlFor={ id } />
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use icon font like `font-awesome` or `google material icons` you can do this with pure css.

Use `::before` or `::after` to control the icon, and use properties `content` or `background` to render desired icon.

```
  <div class="select">
    <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
      <option>11</option>
      <option>12</option>
      <option>13</option>
      <option>14</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

```
.select {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
  background: white;
}

.select::before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  /*If you use font icon, put icon reference here*/
  background: black;
  /* If you use background image, place it here*/
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
  right: 5px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
}


/* Remove default dropdown indicator */

select {
  /* for Firefox */
  -moz-appearance: none;
  /* for Chrome */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}


/* For IE10 */

select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/pjjwTEGOiSPZj1MkUgRW